# How to avoid excessive ram consumption using pathos

Tags: python, memory-management, python-multiprocessing, ram, pathos

This is a rough example of how I leverage multiprocessing with pathos:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool

pool = ProcessingPool(10)
results = pool.map(func, args)
```

Each func's run can take a while. Let's say it's 5 minutes, and `len(args) == 20`.
In this case it'll take around 10 minutes to finish.
During this period ram usage steadily grows and the memory is only freed when all work is done.

The main question: how do I change the approach to free the memory *each time* a process is finished, instead of waiting for all of them to finish? Otherwise, if there are 100 args, the total ram consumption would be 5 times bigger than when there are 20 args, even though they are all being computed in parallel chunks of 10.

Besides, the reason behind memory growth is unclear. I allocate memory at the start of `func`, but the usage grows with time. The return value of func is always 0, I store the results on disk.

Also, is there a way to have a few arrays to reside in a shared memory area? So that each process doesn't have to make its own copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was making plots inside my `func`. To make those plots, I used `matplotlib.pyplot`'s interface. Turns out that matplotlib keeps references to all the figures created via pyplot. This is why ram wasn't released. So the issue has nothing to do with `pathos`. Clearing the figures solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in process pool task supports this via the [maxtasksperchild](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) argument. It's possible to use this class via pathos as described in [this issue](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/138#issuecomment-395450706)

```
import pathos

pool = pathos.pools._ProcessPool(processes=10, maxtasksperchild=1)
results = pool.map(func, args)
```

Setting maxtasksperchild to `1` should mean that each process restarts after every task

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! I tried this. Surprisingly, it did not work :( Ram consumption was still rising until eventually hitting pretty much the same value. However, I was still using `from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool` and `pool = ProcessingPool(10, maxtasksperchild=1)` instead of `pathos.pools._ProcessPool`. Could this be the reason?

Comment: For anyone who'll stumble onto this issue - I also tried the suggested option exactly (`pathos.pools._ProcessPool`), it didn't work either. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  The reason `pathos.pools._ProcessPool` was suggested, is that it is identical to `multiprocess.Pool`, which is the essentially `multiprocessing.Pool` augmented with better serialization -- all of which have the `maxtasksperchild` argument.  I believe `maxtasksperchild` should do what you want, but if it doesn't, then maybe you can open an issue on GitHub?  Also, a fully encapsulated example that reproduces your behavior would be very helpful for others to provide you a solution.  Even if you have to replicate your function with a `time.sleep` or something.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns, thank you for your input. Also, thanks a lot for the work you've done! I've just posted an answer specifying the root cause. It has nothing to do with pathos. I had to clear matplotlib's figures from ram that were implicitly kept there even after the functions have finished their job.